# Vue v3 router on Apache website & HTML5 history mode with different base is not working correctly

Tags: vue.js, apache, vuejs3, vue-router, html5-history

I have a basic testing app with Vue v3 that I want to deploy on an Apache/php web server.
The app it is not served from the root but from a subfolder, 'test'.
I have followed the official docs https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html to make the settings.

So far the code for index.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>T2 test</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
        <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
        <router-link to="/contact">Contact</router-link>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
    <script>
        const Home = {
            template: '<h5>Home</h5>'
        }
        const About = {
            template: '<h5>About</h5>'
        }
        const Contact = {
            template: '<h4>Contact</h4>'
        }

        const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
            history: VueRouter.createWebHistory('/test/'),
            routes: [{
                    path: '/',
                    component: Home
                },
                {
                    path: '/about',
                    component: About
                },
                {
                    path: '/contact',
                    component: Contact
                }
            ],
            base: '/test/'
        })

        const app = Vue.createApp({})
        app.use(router)
        app.mount('#app')
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Inside the /play directory there is the .htaccess file:

```
 <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /test/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It is working partially, in the sense that if browsed from `http://localhost:8080/test/` it is displayed, the links redirect correctly from the app, but there is one (big!) issue: if I browse directly `http://localhost:8080/test/about` or `http://localhost:8080/test/contact` they are not resolved, instead pushing to 404 default error page - `GET http://localhost:8080/test/contact 404 (Not Found)`

It is obviously an incomplete setting, I can't figure out what, please help. Tx.

Comment: Have you tried `RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]` ?

Comment: Just did. No success. Still redirects to 404.

Answer (score 1):

`FallbackResource /test/index.php` - and the problems solved miraculously!